# Symfony 1.4 - Logging working for prod public but not prod admin

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Just trying to set up production logging on a Symfony 1.4 site (yes we've told them to upgrade).

It's logging as expected for public, but it's not generating a file or any logs for admin.

This is my settings.yml in apps/admin/config:

```
prod:
    .settings:
        no_script_name:         false
        logging_enabled:        true
```

And this is my factories.yml in apps/admin/config:

```
prod:
    logger:
        class:   sfFileLogger
        param:
            level:   err
            loggers: ~
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%.log
```

It's exactly the same in apps/public/config and that's logging fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably level set to `err` is too high for what you want to see in the logs under the `admin` app. You can probably try to lower it to `warning` or `notice` in order to see more information in the logs. Check documentation for [all available levels](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories#chapter_05_sub_level).

Also remember that in prod, depending on the traffic, you might have a lot of info logged so your log file could get big quickly!

Make sure to clear the cache after each config change as that's the root cause for 90% of issues with symfony1 :)

Comment: Hi dlondero, thanks for your reply. I originally had the level set to 'info' when I was testing it and it still wasn't logging anything.